# breaking array of chars inside ng-repeat and set each char its own input tag

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i am new to angular and looking for a way take each of the names in the table and break the name in a way that each letter appears in its own `<input>` tag. so if a table cell contains the name "Dave", and user clicks the 'D', input tag containing only this letter is "selected". 
this is the row and the table cell:

```
<tr ng-repeat="name in data">
    <td class="name"><input type="text" ng-model="user_name"></td>
</tr>
```

any help or guidance please?

**UPDATE**

what i actually have it's two ng-repeat's im using to create a table. the table has 3 columns: user_name,script_name and cron_format. the only part i want the end user to be able to change is the cron format, but i want to break the cron_format in a way that if user clicks the "minute" value, the value will be the only one marked and not the all cron_format...
this is the table:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(user_id,row) in data">
<tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in row" ng-init="oldCron = cron_format">
    <td class="userName">{{user(user_id)}}</td>
    <td class="scriptName">{{script(script_id)}}</td>
    <td class="cronFormat">
        <input type="text"  ng-model="cron_format" ng-blur="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format,oldCron)"/></td>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: It might be easier for us to help you if we have a bit more information about how your `data` is structured... where is the 'array of chars' coming from?

Comment: You can ng-repeat on a string directly and it will repeat over each character in the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a more complete implementation. You data comes through in a scope object `$scope.data`. This object contains an array of objects representing 'people' with keys for their 'name'. This implementation include a scope function `$scope.letters` that breaks a name string down into its respective individual characters.

[**JSFIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/nu4nc55v/7/)

*HTML:*

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        <table>
            <tr ng-repeat="person in data">
                <td class="name">
                    <input type="text" ng-repeat="letter in letters(person.name) track by $index" value="{{letter}}">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>   
</div>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    $scope.data = [
        {name:'Jim'},
        {name:'Dave'},
        {name:'Chelsea'}
    ];

    $scope.letters = function(rawname) {
        var lettersarray = rawname.split('');
        return lettersarray;
    };

}]);
```

*Note, the `track by $index` is necessary for any name that includes repeat characters (ex. 'Bill')

Comment: @user3194267 – see the re-edited answer above with a full jsfiddle example showing implementation of function that breaks a name down to its individual letters

Comment: Your letters function seems superfluous, you can just use "letter in person.name". Also, I'm not sure of the actual goal of the original question but I'm curious if they want each letter in the input tied back to the index position of the original name??? It's an odd question and I'm curious what the intent truly is as it seems pointless other than as an exercise.